# Code body expands way too far to the right

Tags: bug, code-block

I just viewed [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233426/rock-paper-scissors-game-java) question on Code Review. For me on both Chrome and Edge, the code shoots off way to the right. This messes with the user card, and the hot/related bar:

[image]

I can't say I've ever seen this before. The lines are abnormally long though.

(Yes, I know this is the third bug report I've filed. I don't know why everything is breaking around me today).

Comment: I've seen the same thing just now on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59184996/ado-inserts-causes-error-in-previous-records-on-continuous-forms-vba).

Comment: Was going to log this, making posts unreadable in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Oops. I didn't even check for an existing post because I had just gone over new Meta posts a little over an hour ago. Apparently this is super new.